# Correct way to describe and handle be'ed in English:

Tags: tenses

I want to reward you -> You should be rewarded.

I want to be nice to you -> You should be be'd nice to.

What's the fancy linguistic way to describe this gap in English, and what's the right way to say it?

Comment: Passive applies to transitive clauses with verbs. _Be nice to_ is a predicate adjective, so passive can't apply to it. The right way to say it is the active: _I want to be nice to you -> I should be nice to you_. Oh, and btw, there is **no** "be'ed" in English.

Comment: @JohnLawler I think colloquially you might get away with *be been nice to*, with the idiom recategorized as a transitive; but certainly *You should be treated nicely* would be more acceptable in any register.

Comment: Sure. _Treat_ is, of course, a verb, so passive can work. The mistake is thinking that because _be nice_ is an active predicate adjective (it can occur in the progressive and imperatives, for instance), and because it's transitivized by _to_, that it's therefore a transitive verbal phrase that can be passivized. But passive requires a verb to be inflected and no adjective will fit the sprockets properly.

Comment: @JohnLawler My sense is that the OP understands that *be'ed* is not a real word, he's looking for a deeper explanation of why English doesn't allow this kind of construction.

Comment: Because of the nature and limitations of the Passive construction. This is subject to change, over sufficiently long times.

Comment: It seems to me that, in addition to the transitive/copular verb disconnect mentioned by others, "you" is direct object in the first sentence, which makes it the subject when you "reverse" the sentence by adopting passive voice. In your second sentence, it's a indirect object. How do you "flip" indirect objects?

Comment: @ChrisSunami You seem to be criticising English when you ask why it doesn't *allow this kind of construction*; albeit it being a very convoluted construction. I can't speak for many languages but I can tell you that French has no passive voice at all, even for transitive verbs. You cannot actually say *I was given a book* other than as *On m'a donné un livre* literally *Someone gave me a book*.

Comment: @WS2 I do not dispute that your suggested French phrase is perfectly idiomatic. However: [“La **voix passive d’un verbe** se fait avec l’auxiliaire *être* suivi du participe passé du verbe. L’auxiliaire est conjugué au même temps que le verbe de la voix active.”](http://www.francaisfacile.com/exercices/exercice-francais-2/exercice-francais-9841.php)

Comment: No English past participle has an ending such as 'ed. And that to be has no passive is basic grammar.

Comment: @tchrist Yes one could say *j'étais donné un livre* but it is far less common than *on m'a donné...* in my experience.

Answer (score 6):

There is no gap here.

In the first case, *reward* is a transitive verb (it takes an object) and therefore it can be used in a passive voice (*be rewarded*).

In the second example the verb is the copular *be*. It has no passive voice — it would make no sense if it did.

I can *be* but you can't be *beed*. What would that mean? It would require that you were the object of my *being*, which contradicts the definition of the verb! I am the object of my own *being*. (Here I'm using *being* as a verb, not a noun).

The role of the copular *be* here is to [express having a state or quality](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/be?searchDictCode=all) and *you* is an indirect object. This structure has no passive form.

Here are a couple of examples of this.

> I was angry towards Mary.
>
> I became agitated at the photocopier.

If the verb is transitive, the passive form is possible.

> active: I sent flowers to Mary.
>
> passive: Mary was sent flowers by me.

If you want a passive form for the second sentence, you'll need to pick a construction that allows it. For example,

> I want to appreciate you.
>
> You should be appreciated.